# Where is the serial number on T440s?

Tags: thinkpad, serial-number

I need the machine type and serial number of my T440s. I can't find it at the bottom of the laptop. Is this normal? I remember that it was clearly visible on my old T420s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that case you might appreciate this approach (run from command line):

```
wmic.exe csproduct list full
```

It gave me this output on an X200:

```
Description=Computer System Product 
IdentifyingNumber=S3R1AL
Name=xxxxxx
SKUNumber=
UUID=-removed-
Vendor=LENOVO 
Version=ThinkPad X200
```

Comment: Awesome, I was actually looking for a software-way to do this.

Comment: Great, after all, looking at the bottom of a laptop is almost as annoying as removing the battery. So i also prefer the "soft" way. And btw. thanks, now i know where the stickers are on our W530s. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Found it: Unlike other models, the T440s displays the S/N and machine type in the battery compartment. Thus, to see it, you have to remove the battery.

Answer (score -1):

From the command line:

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```